# Detection of rectangular bright area in a Image using OpenCv

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, opencv

I have previously asked a question  [Marking an interest point in an image using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476416/marking-an-interest-point-in-an-image-using-c). I used the same solution and got the required point using the adaptive threshold and [Blob Detection Algorithm](http://geekblog.nl/entry/24)(Growing Regions). I have the original source figure where I want to detect the rectangular region at the center

## Original Image:

[image: Original Image].But after I used the algorithm, I got something like this(details are visible if you open it in a new tab)

## Marked Image:

[image] where apart from the rectangular region the bright day light illuminated spots are also visible. I have used bilateral filtering but still I am not able to detect the rectangular region.But this algorithm works for the Night image where the background is more darker as expected.

Can someone suggest me whether the same algorithm with some modifications is sufficient or any other efficient ways are available..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a simple combination of *blur* & *threshold* I managed to get this result (resized for viewing purposes):

[image]

After that, applying *erosion* & [the squares.cpp technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863060/176769) (which is a sample from OpenCV) outputs:

[image]

which is almost the result you are looking for: the bottom part of the rectangle was successfully detected. All you need to do is **increase the height** of the detected rectangle (red square) to fit your area of interest.

Code:

```
Mat img = imread(argv[1]);

    // Blur
Mat new_img = img.clone();
medianBlur(new_img, new_img, 5);

// Perform threshold
double thres = 210;
double color = 255;
threshold(new_img, new_img, thres, color, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
imwrite("thres.png", new_img);

// Execute erosion to improve the detection
int erosion_size = 4;   
Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS,
                                   Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
                                   Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
erode(new_img, new_img, element);
imwrite("erode.png", new_img);

vector<vector<Point> > squares;
find_squares(new_img, squares);
std::cout << "squares: " << squares.size() << std::endl;

draw_squares(img, squares);

imwrite("area.png", img);
```

**EDIT**:

The `find_squares()` function returns a vector with all the squares found in the image. Because it iterates on every channel of the image, on your example it successfully detects the rectangular region in each of them, so printing `squares.size()` outputs `3`.

As a *square* can be seen as a vector of 4 (X,Y) coordinates, OpenCV express this concept as `vector<Point>` allowing you to access the X and Y part the coordinate.

Now, printing `squares` revelead that the points were detected in a counterclockwise direction:

```
1st ------ 4th
 |          |
 |          |
 |          |
2nd ------ 3rd
```

Following this example, its fairly obvious that if you need to increase the height of the rectangle you need to change the Y of the 1st and 4th points:

```
for (int i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < squares[i].size(); j++)
    {
    //  std::cout << "# " << i << " " << squares[i][j].x << ","<< squares[i][j].y << std::endl;
        if (j == 0 || j == 3)
            squares[i][j].y = 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Karlphilip wow..Thats Great..Thanks a lot for your help.I am getting the desired result for the darker images also but with hardcoded threshold say(around 80).If it goes away from the region.I cannot find the squares. So I used Otsu thresholding value but I have to add 30 for the satisfactory detection. Any other way to detect both the  darker and brighter images

Comment: That is the only one I can think of.

Comment: @Karlphilip..Using this algorithm I want to just find the coordinates of the center of the rectangular area in the original figure. any ideas that I can approach.

Comment: Well, since you already have the coordinates of the edges of the rectangle, a simple math operation will give you the center coordinates, wouldn't it? Let's keep one question per thread. If you have more questions feel free to ask them in new threads.

Comment: @lakshmikant You shouldn't add more points to the vector, just change the ones you have. A `cv::Point` stores a X,Y coordinate. You are interested in change the Y coordinate to 0 in 2 points. Remember, a square has 4 points.

Comment: @karlphilip.. one more doubt..how do you find the maximum Y value for the picture? ie the bottom edge

Comment: @lakshmikant Reflect upon the `for` loops I added when the answer was updated. Unfortunately, we have a policy of 1 question per thread, I think I ended up answering a few more than that. I encourage you to make new questions in new threads. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In the image shown above, I would suggest

1. either a normal thresholding operation which should work pretty well or
2. a line-wise chain-code "calculation" or
3. finding gradients in your histogram.

There would be plenty of other solutions.
I would consider to subtract the background shading if this is consistent.